# "Java Application" or "JavaFX Application" in NetBeans for desktop?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to design a desktop application in Java using the Netbeans IDE.

When creating a "New Project" in Netbeans, what should I select - "Java Application" under "Java" or "JavaFX Application" under "JavaFX"?

Comment: If it's a Swing app, choose "Java Application".  If you're writing JavaFX, then the other is the obvious choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short Java Application for Swing based application and JavaFX for JavaFX based application.

It depends on what you're building. Swing has more components around for it (3rd party as well as built in) and not all of them have made their way to the newer JavaFX platform yet. On the other hand, FX provides different set of capabilities, and it's the way forward especially if building something from scratch.

Comment: okay, so basically i want to design a inventory management software, and i'm confused which option to select from "java application" and "javaFX application". I mean would it be a huge difference in back coding and drag & drop UI designing ?

Comment: @Yash I would recommend you to read this article http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2273822

Comment: Thanks, it's just that i have used swing earlier so there would be no problem or difference with coding in javaFX..?